# Wait for function to finish before calling it again

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create the appearance of typed text using JS. Currently, the `output` function creates a new DOM element and `typeText` creates the typing animation.
Here is the code:

```js
function typeText(text, outputElement) {
    var i = 0;
    var paragText = "";
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        paragText += text.charAt(i);
        outputElement.innerText = paragText;
        i++;
        if (text.length == i)
            clearInterval(interval);
    }, 70)
}
function output(text, colour){
    var outputElement = document.createElement("p");
    outputElement.setAttribute("class", "output");
    outputElement.setAttribute("style", "color: " + colour + ";");
    var outputWrapper = document.getElementById("output");
    outputWrapper.appendChild(outputElement);
    typeText(text, outputElement);
}
output("Test output 1", "red");
output("Test output 2", "green");
output("Test output 3", "blue");
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head></head>
        <body>
            <div class = "output-wrapper" id = "output">
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

When loading the page, all 3 animations happen simultaneously. How can I make the animations happen one after the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `await` for a `Promise` when calling a `setInterval`. This way, the function becomes `async` and it gets called after finishing each time:

```js
async function typeText(text, outputElement) {
  var i = 0;
  var paragText = "";
  await new Promise(resolve => setInterval(function () {
    paragText += text.charAt(i);
    outputElement.innerText = paragText;
    i++;
    if (text.length == i)
      resolve();
  }, 70))
}

async function output(text, colour){
  var outputElement = document.createElement("p");
  outputElement.setAttribute("class", "output");
  outputElement.setAttribute("style", "color: " + colour + ";");
  var outputWrapper = document.getElementById("output");
  outputWrapper.appendChild(outputElement);
  await typeText(text, outputElement);
}

const init = async function() {
  const outStrs = [
    {text:"Test output 1",color:"red"},
    {text:"Test output 2",color:"green"},
    {text:"Test output 3",color:"blue"},
  ];
  for (i =0; i < outStrs.length; i++){         
    await output(outStrs[i].text, outStrs[i].color);     
  }
}();
```

```html
<div class = "output-wrapper" id = "output"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've tried using a for loop in the init function `var i;
    for (i =0; i < outStrs.length; i++){
        await output(outStrs[i], "red");
    }
    await output("Test output 1", "red");
    await output("Test output 2", "green");
    await output("Test output 3", "blue");` and this does not display anything. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Henry you're welcome. I edited the answer to iterate over the list as you mentioned

Answer (score 2):

A solution with `setTimeout` and array

```js
var delay = 90; // Writing speed

var arr = [     // Text and color Array
    ['Lorem ipsum dolor', 'red'],
    ['Consectetur adipisicing', 'green'],
    ['Earum voluptas', 'blue'],
];

function typeText(text, outputElement) {
    var i = 0;
    var paragText = "";
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        paragText += text.charAt(i);
        outputElement.innerText = paragText;
        i++;
        if (text.length == i)
            clearInterval(interval);
    }, delay)
}
function output(text, colour) {
    var outputElement = document.createElement("p");
    outputElement.setAttribute("class", "output");
    outputElement.setAttribute("style", "color: " + colour + ";");
    var outputWrapper = document.getElementById("output");
    outputWrapper.appendChild(outputElement);
    typeText(text, outputElement);
}

// Calculates setTimeout: Push the start time of each line in the array
var time = 0;
for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    time = time + delay + arr[i-1][0].length * delay;
    arr[i].push(time);
}

// Execute the writing process
var n = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        output(arr[n][0], arr[n][1]);
        n++;
    }, arr[i][2]);
}
```

```html
<div class="output-wrapper" id="output">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer